# Error when using Class Modules

Tags: vb6

I am using a class module in my project. I made an EXE of the project. But this EXE gives error when I run this on another PC... even in mine PC, if run from another folder.

I get following error - 5 - Invalid procedure call or argument.

Can somebody guide me how to use the Class module while making EXE..?

Comment: What the heck is a class module? In VB6 you can create a class or a module (global static functions and variables)

Comment: @Jan - http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110715222930AAW5OF5

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: Thanks for the link. I was just calling that a class.

Comment: OK, back to the topic:) You should show some code of your class to get help. When its running on one folder but not on another i guess you so something with files and folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class module is analogous to a form module or a standard module (which is called just "module") in VB6.  Basically, anything that has its own code window is a module.  Class modules are saved with a .cls extension.

The probable reason for your error is that you can't see the class at the point you're attempting to use it.

Your question could mean several different things.  Please give me a list of all the projects (maybe you have just one, but you could have more), all the forms, all the standard modules (just called "modules"), and all the class modules you are using.  That will help me understand better how to answer your question.